# Sublime Text 3 settings always lost in a new file

Tags: sublimetext3, indentation

I've switched to sass recently because I like the indented flavor of it but now I have a problem with my SB3 text editor:

My initial tab settings are too big for sass (it just takes too much place tab size is set by default to 4) so what I did to change that I just went to

```
Preferences -> Settings More -> Syntax Specific User
```

And then I added:

```
{
  "tab_size": 2,
  "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}
```

And here is the trick, it works on the document itself *only* when I create/open a file and then press tab it's like I never changed it but within the settings document it works perfectly, I have tried many solutions but none of them were successful

Comment: What is the filename of the syntax-specific settings file (probably CSS.sublime-settings)? Do the other files have the same syntax setted? If you open another sass file and go to Preferences...Syntax-specfic, is the same file opened? Check also the setting *detect_indentation*

Comment: Man, I love you, I didn't catch that those settings are specific to what extension file you righting in it .. waouuu. thanks a lot IT WOOOOORKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was provided to me by sergioFC ! Thanks a lot man !
The answer is that those spec setting depends on what file you are at the moment when you open the spec.
For example if I have a .css file, and I open the Syntax Specific user, everything I write in you will be applied only to the files that have the same extension.

Thanks a lot @ sergioFC !!!